# Hijacking __NR_read and bash crashes (caf user?)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm hijacking `__NR_read` (`sys_read` call) and each time I hijack the original syscall with my own syscall, it causes a crash in bash (in all open KDE "konsoles") (that is, as soon as I hijack `sys_open`).

I'm wondering if this is a bug in my code (probably) or it's happening because of something else.

My question is: if the crash is caused because of my code, what is causing it exactly and how (if possible) can I fix it? If the crash isn't caused by my code, what is causing it?

My code is here: https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon/tree/master/procmon_kmodule

`syshijack.c` is where I get the syscall table and `hookfns.c` is where I hijack the syscalls.

PS: I already asked this question before here [Hijacking sys calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878068/hijacking-sys-calls) but it changed now, as the crash happens as soon as I hijack the syscall.

*** EDIT ***

I think the bug is comming from hook/unhook calls, so I created an issue https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon/issues/7
Anyways, I can't see what is causing the crash/freeze.

Answer (score 1):

Hook engine works fine on my `x86_64` without `IA32` part and without your code in `hooked_sys_read` except `r = real_sys_read()`. Digging your code I've found that there might be a problem with IA32 hooking as:

```
#define HOOK(F, RF, FF) RF = sys_call_table[F]; sys_call_table[F] = FF;
#ifdef CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION
    #define HOOK_IA32(F, RF, FF) ia32_sys_call_table[F] = FF;
#endif
```

.. so `HOOK_IA32` doesn't stores the `RF` value as it implemented in `HOOK` macro. Check it out.

As for the others... The `path_from_fd` seems ugly to me.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Sorry for not answering before. I was at the office. Yes indeed, there was a bug in the HOOK IA32 macro. I just pushed a fix. Anyways, that wasn't the problem. The virtual machine I'm testing on keeps freezing whenever I call hook/unhook a few times.

Comment: Hey, do you know that `VirtualBox` (and may be other VM's) doesn't emulate `sidt` instruction properly? I've found that `sidt` returns wrong value in my case and used different symbol lookup method to get `sys_call_table` entry. It seems that you've the same problem...

Comment: Oh. So perhaps my module is working just fine on real machines? I wasn't willing to test it on my real machine, but maybe I should. Let me give it a try

Comment: Nope, bad decision. It just froze my entire machine and I had to power it off... :(